# A quick music puzzle

Tags: riddle, knowledge, wordplay, music

What am I, and what is the next note?

- > Some call me unemotional and austere, but I will bring the sunshine into anyone's life.
- > I am my next note, though we are not the same.
- > I'm a common complaint from students of language.

Hint:

> Clue 3: It's all ----- to me!

Let me know if this should me on [Music.SE](https://music.stackexchange.com) instead!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are

> the musical note **RE**

Some call me unemotional and austere, but I will bring the sunshine into anyone's life.

> RE on the subject line of emails is a shortcut (austere) and lends the correspondence an air of formality (unemotional). But in REality, you are a drop of golden sun! (Do-Re-Mi song reference as guessed by @MobileGlick)

I am my next note, though we are not the same.

> MI (me), a name you call yourself, is also the next note to you

I'm a common complaint from students of language.

> Could be a reference to the confusing contraction of "re" in "your" vs "you're" or the ambiguity of tense ("you are" vs "you were"). This might also refer to [Recursively Enumerable languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_enumerable_language) which I will not even attempt to explain :P

Comment: That's the right answer, but you didn't solve some of the clues! Should I accept? I'm new here.

Comment: Also relatively new here. Can you specify which clue(s) I didn't get right? Also didn't notice the hint before.

Comment: The hint is new.

Comment: rot13(Lbh qvqa'g trg gur fghqrag'f pbzcynvag - 'Vg'f nyy Terrx gb zr!' Terrx orpnhfr bs gur Cueltvna zbqr (juvpu fgnegf ba Er, nxn Q), juvpu vf gur svefg pyhr - nhfgrer = sevtvq, juvpu fbhaqf yvxr Cueltvna (vg'f n fgergpu V xabj))

Comment: rot13(Jubn! V nterr gung gur nhfgrer-sevtvq-Cueltvna pbaarpgvba vf n ovg bs n fgergpu rfcrpvnyyl sbe gubfr bs hf yrff zhfvpnyyl vapyvarq :C)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are

> I think it's SO. Maybe LA? (Reasoning ahead)

Some call me unemotional and austere

> DO perhaps?  I thought you may be referring to just a normal deer (a doe), but both John Doe and dough also came to mind.

but I will bring the sunshine into anyone's life.

> Clearly, this must be ray for the note RE.

I am my next note, though we are not the same.

> ME.  Referring to itself.  The notes ME and RE are not the same, though perhaps similar.

I'm a common complaint from students of language.

> (It's all ----- to me!) Maybe it's ”So far.” The note FA can sound like far with an accent. People complain about distance all the time.

Finally we have:

> After the note FA we would have the answer **SO**.  However, might be a stretch, if we count ”so” in ”so far” then it may be that the next note is **LA**.

Answer (score 0):

Is the answer

> Sew

Reasoning:

> bringing sunshine refers to "Ray" and next is "Me" in Do Re Mi from the sound of music. So the next one would be Far, and that leaves the answer to be Sew.

Comment: You're on the right track! You've missed the first part of the first clue and the last clue though.

Comment: Let me know if you'd like a hint